# Is sheltering in this sentence gerund or present participle

Tags: present-participles

'Sheltering thieving juveniles causes harm to all' Can two present participles be used sequentially

Comment: It's a gerund - '[The act of] sheltering'. The juveniles are doing the thieving but not the sheltering.

Comment: You can certainly have at least ***three*** in a row: ***Endorsing fining thieving** juveniles could be seen as a vote-winning strategy for some politicians.* And I don't see any reason why *in principle* we shouldn't be able to continue such "daisy-chaining" indefinitely. It might be a bit contrived, but I'm sure my example could be extended with an initial ***Mocking***. (To mock the idea of endorsing the fining of juveniles who thieve is a concept I can get my head round! :)

Comment: Most importantly, "sheltering" is a verb, and that's all you really need to know. Traditional grammar calls it a gerund, simply because it's head of a clause functioning as subject, a function typically performed by a noun phrase. "Thieving" is a present participle modifying "juveniles".